# PHP - Way to load page with zero database calls

Tags: php, mysql, websocket, load

I am working on a page which is having a more than 100 database calls and it takes too much time to load the webpage.

I am thinking of loading a page with zero database calls. I have following ways in my mind -

1. Create an HTML copy of my page using a cron job which run frequently in every 5 min and then load it using file_get_contents.
2. Create a txt file of values of database result and then load it into a page.
3. Using a websockets - when there is new data it updates the page.

I need an expert opinion from you guys :)

Comment: This is what query caching is for. However.... If the data is constantly changing than I would use websockets to push only the changed data.  Or maybe storing current data in localStorage object, and update only new data

Comment: Why go from 100 calls to 0? How about 50 or 40 or 30 or 20 or...?

Comment: @KyleK - Yes I had that in mind but the values on my pages are frequently updating and to work it with memcache/caches it should call  database atleast once. My thnking is that there will be one process that will call the database and there will be other page which creates a copy of that page and then loads it for user view

Comment: @Rasclatt - I already reduced the db calls from 300 to 100 :) but page is still slow ( fast as compared to previous )

Comment: Holy cow...that's just a crap-load of calls!!

Comment: query caching with some expiry might do the work.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using some framework like CodeIgniter, you can manage page level as well as database query level caching. Query caching comes with expiry so no need to worry about updating data.

For plain php, I used to write whole output to some file and then check datetime to serve or update the same.

At the start of php file,

```
 <?php
 $cachefile = "some-unique-name.html";
 $cachetime = 864000;

  if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {

   readfile($cachefile);       
   exit;   
   }  

  // if no file or too old, render and capture HTML page.
 ob_start();

 session_start(); 
 ?>

 ------ output all your html code here ----

 <?php $fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w+');   
 fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());   
 fclose($fp);

 // Send browser output   
 ob_end_flush();
 ob_flush();  ?>
```

at the end!

Answer (score 0):

have you normalized the tables in those databases?

I had a similar problem. A bad designing of tables can mess with you

Comment: Yes I also faced same situation before and db calls were around 300 and after normalizing tables I managed to reduced it to 100 with faster execution

Comment: then you should try reducing further before trying caching

Comment: I am not in favor of caching. What I want it 0 database calls when user opens the page. If I reduced it to 20 and if there are 1000 users accessing the page same time then there will be 20000 database calls and I want to avoid that situation